# echo image tag in php according to a value?

Tags: php

so I am using php to retrieve data from mysql database. This data is in the form of a number. I want to echo the same number of images tags according to that number. I do not want to use if statement because I do not know what the number will be (it is dynamic prosses). Any thoughts ?
for example if the number is 5 the result should be :

```
<img src=''>
<img src=''>
<img src=''>
<img src=''>
<img src=''>
```

Comment: Why would you ever want to do this, so if you have a number 2,345 it will create 2,345 image tags but how do you plan on populating those image tags and what not

Comment: so if your number is N you want to do a [for loop](http://au2.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.for.php) N times?

Comment: @ChrisJamesChampeau. Doesn't have to be 2,345 times, could just be 10 max and that's a totally valid case scenario

Comment: yes thanks it is for loop. I totally forgot about it. I will choose your answer.

Comment: @Ben why it is not letting me choose best answer ?

Comment: @SaadAlhly these were comments, answers are below..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do a [for loop](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.for.php)

with `$n` your number from the db:

```
for($i=0;$i<$n;$i++):
?>
<img src='path/to/image.jpg'>
<?php
endfor;
```

Answer (score 1):

Try something like:

```
for ($count=0; $count<$row['tagcount']; $count++) {

   echo("<img src=''>");

}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this...

```
$number = $number[fromdatabase];
$array = range(1,$number);
foreach ($array as $img) {
    echo "<img src=''></img>";
}
```

Now you will have img tags for the number in your database